# Unknown error with Psycopg2, Postgres on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql, selenium

I added his line to my .bash_profile

```
# Postgres new config for OSX Mavericks
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
alias psql="(. ~/.bash_profile; unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH; psql)";

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And it is causing the unkown error below:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

But this is the only way that I could get PosgreSQL working again with my Django App.  Does anyone know what this error is, or if it can be worked around some way by changing the PATH or something like that?

**[edit]**

I believe that this is also causing an issue with Python Selenium because I am no longer able to run Selenium tests.  Here is the error that I'm getting when I try:

```
   WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart\n  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib\n  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libJPEG.dylib\n in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib\n'
```

Thanks

Comment: You're putting two different versions of PostgreSQL on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I think you probably just need to set the `PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that both point to the same PostgreSQL binaries. The issue with libJPEG is because `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3` (presumably EnterpriseDB's PostgreSQL installer, with PgAdmin-III?) bundles its own libjpeg that is not compatible with the system libjpeg. You shouldn't add this to the global `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: i deleted that ~/.bash_profile patch and just symlinked the postres to /usr/lib/ and it worked. thnx

Comment: Hi, I know this is over an year old, but how exactly did you resolve this issue? I was able to solve the ssl issues via symlinking the /usr/lib to the postgres ones, but unable to figure this guy out. Thank you!

Comment: Recently for me is was just adding Postgres to the PATH to get it to work like so `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:${PATH}"`