# webdriver exception in using selenium with Psycopg2, Postgres on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: django, macos, postgresql, selenium

I use `Postgres` in my Django app. PostgreSQL was installed with the EnterpriseDB "one-click" installer.

I issued this command `export $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib` on bash to make Postgres work.

No change to my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is made.

```
python manage.py runserver works fine.
```

But `selenium` fails

```
Python manage.py test myapp
```

I get the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart\n  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib\n  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libJPEG.dylib\n in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib\n'
```

what is the fix needed?

I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455476/unknown-error-with-psycopg2-postgres-on-mac-osx-mavericks) had same issue. but a solution to how it worked is not posted. some suggestions to make it work?

P.S: 
Right now I need to issue this command

```
export $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib
```

everytime on the terminal. I can place it `.bash_profile`. but that causes other problems.

Looking inside my PostgreSQL library folder I see:

```
ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/
3rd_party_licenses.txt   data                     installer                pgAdmin3.app             share
Library                  doc                      lib                      pg_env.sh                stackbuilder.app
bin                      include                  license.txt              scripts                  uninstall-postgresql.app

ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/
libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib                  libiconv.2.dylib                       libpq.a                                libwx_macu_adv-2.8.0.dylib
libcrypto.a                            libiconv.dylib                         libpq.dylib                            libwx_macu_adv-2.8.dylib
libcrypto.dylib                        libiconv.la                            libssl.1.0.0.dylib                     libwx_macu_core-2.8.0.8.0.dylib
libecpg.6.5.dylib                      libjpeg.8.dylib                        libssl.a                               libwx_macu_core-2.8.0.dylib
libecpg.6.dylib                        libjpeg.a                              libssl.dylib                           libwx_macu_core-2.8.dylib
libecpg.a                              libjpeg.dylib                          libuuid.16.dylib                       libxml2.2.dylib
libecpg.dylib                          libjpeg.la                             libuuid.a                              libxml2.a
libecpg_compat.3.5.dylib               libpgcommon.a                          libuuid.dylib                          libxml2.dylib
libecpg_compat.3.dylib                 libpgport.a                            libuuid.la                             libxml2.la
libecpg_compat.a                       libpgtypes.3.4.dylib                   libwx_base_carbonu-2.8.0.8.0.dylib     libxslt.1.dylib
libecpg_compat.dylib                   libpgtypes.3.dylib                     libwx_base_carbonu-2.8.0.dylib         libxslt.a
libedit.0.dylib                        libpgtypes.a                           libwx_base_carbonu-2.8.dylib           libxslt.dylib
libedit.a                              libpgtypes.dylib                       libwx_base_carbonu_net-2.8.0.8.0.dylib libxslt.la
libedit.dylib                          libpng16.16.dylib                      libwx_base_carbonu_net-2.8.0.dylib     libz.1.2.8.dylib
libedit.la                             libpng16.a                             libwx_base_carbonu_net-2.8.dylib       libz.1.dylib
libexpat.1.dylib                       libpng16.dylib                         libwx_base_carbonu_xml-2.8.0.8.0.dylib libz.a
libexpat.a                             libpng16.la                            libwx_base_carbonu_xml-2.8.0.dylib     libz.dylib
libexpat.dylib                         libpq.5.6.dylib                        libwx_base_carbonu_xml-2.8.dylib       pkgconfig
libexpat.la                            libpq.5.dylib                          libwx_macu_adv-2.8.0.8.0.dylib         postgresql
```

Comment: Looks like the EnterpriseDB package for PostgreSQL right? Please report this as a bug to them. They should not be packaging libjpeg in the same library directory as the PostgreSQL libraries, for this exact reason: it means you can't set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to use the desired `libpq` etc without also putting an undesired incompatible libJPEG on the path. You could work around this - if you don't need or use PgAdmin-III - by removing PgAdmin-III, libjpeg, libtiff, etc from `/Library/PostgresSQL/9.3/`. Don't delete anything though - just move and take note of where it was.

Comment: @CraigRinger: can you please elaborate? I have pasted my `ls` in the edit above. please direct me to move which ones. Thanks

Comment: I don't have a Mac and Apple don't allow the running of OS X in a VM. So I can't test it, and without the ability to test it I can't safely give you specific instructions. Please raise this as an issue on the EnterpriseDB forums (they don't hang out here and won't see this otherwise), because EnterpriseDB need to fix the package so this doesn't happen. They may be able to give you step by step instructions for a workaround since they have access to Mac systems.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I am sorry, I am new to using Postgres. so I actually don't know exactly what I am doing, but I am just following instructions that I get from web. so I dont know how and where to raise an issue. Moreover, I dont know what error I am facing. All I know is I have some error..

Comment: As you're using the EnterpriseDB packages for PostgreSQL, please mention this as a packaging issue to them here: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/forums/show/9.page

Comment: @CraigRinger:  any temporary hack to make it work?

Comment: Use a wrapper script that sets `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` where required and then invokes the real command you want. So that way you don't have to set it globally but still get it for the right commands.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The answer posted below seems to work for me. Thanks for rendering your valuable info.

Comment: I still think you really should raise this issue on the EDB forums. They won't improve it if you don't report it.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I did raise the issue, but not sure if I did correctly. Lets see..

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT want to link: `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `bash` or in `.bash_profile`

I did that and had a lot of unexpected errors as you are experiencing and noted above.

The fix is to link the `libssl` and `libcrypto` from Postgres = `/Library/Postgres/9.3/lib` to your system `/usr/lib`

Here are the commands. First copy your libraries over from `Postgres` to the system `/usr/lib/`:

```
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

Then update (or create) the `/usr/lib` symlinks for this libraries. The command is `ln -fs`:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Comment: I don't know what is going on here. but I just pasted your commands and it works!!!. If you spare a minute to explain what is going on here and why these errors come up, it will be helpful for Postgres/django community. Thank you very much for helping out

Comment: I'm not at all convinced it's safe to go symlinking libraries into `/usr/lib`. You'll probably get away with it if you're not replacing any existing libraries, but it's really just a workaround for the conflict.